# NSLog Not Appearing After Initial Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nslog

XCode 5.0 Console Not Showing After Exiting App and Reopening. I put a simple NSLog in the next screen that I push to and there is no logging of it in my console. This makes it a pain to debug! I segue from one screen to a tabbar controller, if that helps?

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint to make sure the line is actually called?

Comment: @cabellicar123 Yes I did, I put in a viewdidLoad method for all of my screens. Didn't help. :(

Comment: Do you mean killing the app from tasks by 'Exiting App'? If so, as @jd. says the debugger exits after killing the app. Or if you mean suspending by 'Home' button or swapping to another app, then it's a weird issue.

Comment: @KorayAlkan Suspending.

Comment: When you say it didn't help, you mean that the lines were called and still not printed?

Answer (score 0):

Are you in debugger mode?  If so, when you exit the app it usually exits the debugger.  As  cabellicar123 mentions - use the breakpoints.  They are way more effective debugging than NSLogs in most cases anyway.